# Consuming XML in restful post

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jax-rs

I have been doing lots of googling lately trying to find a decent documentation/tutorial to consume XML in JAVA RestFUL implementation of webservice. My requirements are simple

- I want to consume XML

Which means that i need XML in raw. I don't need any JAXB binding or any objection conversation. Can someone point me to some decent tutorial or post something here

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public void consumeXML (/*something here- duno what*/){
    //something here as well
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend specifying an `InputStream` as the method parameter.

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public void consumeXML ( InputStream xml ){
    //do something with the XML string
}
```

Then the `InputStream` can be processed using any number of technologies:  DOM, SAX, StAX, JAXB, etc.

Comment: @EmAe - I'm the EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) lead, so the documentation I have is about leveraging JAXB for the XML handling:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-45.html

Answer (score 0):

```
public void consumeXML ( String xml ){
    //do something with the XML string
}
```